# reassigning expanded recarray field

Tags: python, numpy, recarray

I am loading file data into a numpy recarray and subsequently filling in known gaps with NaNs.  However, I can not find a way to increase the size of the field in the recarray in order to  reassign the array with filled gaps.  An example of my problem (given below) throws a valueerror about broadcasting from a larger to smaller shape.

using python 2.7.6.1, numpy 1.8.1-6

Thanks, Rob

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma

a1 = np.arange(0,20,1)
a2 = np.arange(100,120,1)

X = np.recarray((20,), dtype=[('g', float), ('h', int)])
X['g'][:] = a1
X['h'][:] = a2

for afield in X.dtype.names:
    Y = X[afield].copy(order='K')
    for icnt in range(0,3):
        Y = np.insert(Y, 5, np.nan, axis=0)

    ma.resize(X[afield], (len(Y),) )
    X[afield][:] =  Y[:]
```

Comment: for the start the first column is a float array but then you can not convert float NaN to integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not "expand" your recarray X. Recarrays cannot be expanded per label (name/column), which is what you were hoping to do with `ma.resize`. Note that `ma.resize` *returns* a new (masked) array with the new shape without altering the arrays passed to it, but in your code you are not using the return value. So that line doesn't do anything. To clarify:

```
X[afield] = ma.resize(X[afield], (len(Y),) )
```

would also not work, because record arrays cannot be expanded per label ('column').
If you want to expand a recarray, you'll need to do it in one go (with functions from `np.lib.recfunctions`), so add an entirely new column or add several new records for all existing columns.

That being said, why not just try this:

```
>>> Y = np.arange(20, dtype=np.float)
>>> Ynan = np.insert(Y, (5,)*3, (np.nan,)*3)
>>> X = np.rec.fromarrays([Ynan, Ynan+100], names='g,h')
>>> X
rec.array([(0.0, 100.0), (1.0, 101.0), (2.0, 102.0), (3.0, 103.0),
       (4.0, 104.0), (nan, nan), (nan, nan), (nan, nan), (5.0, 105.0),
       (6.0, 106.0), (7.0, 107.0), (8.0, 108.0), (9.0, 109.0),
       (10.0, 110.0), (11.0, 111.0), (12.0, 112.0), (13.0, 113.0),
       (14.0, 114.0), (15.0, 115.0), (16.0, 116.0), (17.0, 117.0),
       (18.0, 118.0), (19.0, 119.0)], 
      dtype=[('g', '<f8'), ('h', '<f8')])
```

Note that you cannot convert the 2nd column (label 'h') to an int, because `np.nan` is a floating point type. If you tried, you'd get garbage:

```
>>> X['h'].astype(np.int)
array([                 100,                  101,                  102,
                        103,                  104, -9223372036854775808,
       -9223372036854775808, -9223372036854775808,                  105,
                        106,                  107,                  108,
                        109,                  110,                  111,
                        112,                  113,                  114,
                        115,                  116,                  117,
                        118,                  119])
```

I think what you're after is actually **masked record arrays**:

```
>>> import numpy.ma.mrecords as mrecords
>>> 
>>> X = np.rec.fromarrays([Ynan, (Ynan+100).astype(np.int)], names='g,h')
>>> Z = np.ma.array(X, mask=np.isnan(Ynan))
>>> Z2 = Z.view(mrecords.mrecarray)
>>> 
>>> Z2
masked_records(
    g : [0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 -- -- -- 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0 10.0 11.0 12.0 13.0 14.0
 15.0 16.0 17.0 18.0 19.0]
    h : [100 101 102 103 104 -- -- -- 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115
 116 117 118 119]
    fill_value : (1e+20, 999999)
              )
>>> 
>>> Z2['h']
masked_array(data = [100 101 102 103 104 -- -- -- 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115
 116 117 118 119],
             mask = [False False False False False  True  True  True False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

As you can see, the "columns" of Z2 have the desired dtype (float and int), are accessible by their column names and have some of the data masked.